# Error retrieving permission description

Tags: android, android-permissions

My ApkInfo activity should display the permissions along with permissions description. But during runtime it displays the permission description in an unknown format. In the following code the AppData class is used to initialize the packageInfo with the user selected app populated from a list of installed apps.

```
public class ApkInfo extends Activity { 

PackageInfo packageInfo;
PermissionInfo pi;
PackageManager pm;    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.apkinfo);
PermissionInfo pi = new PermissionInfo();
AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
packageInfo = appData.getPackageInfo(); 
if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions != null){
String[] permissions = getPermissions(packageInfo.requestedPermissions, pi);
}
private String[] getPermissions(String[] requestedPermissions, PermissionInfo pinfo) {
pm = getPackageManager();
String permission = "";
for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
try {
pinfo = pm.getPermissionInfo(requestedPermissions[i], PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

try {

pinfo.loadDescription(pm).toString();

}catch(NullPointerException ex){

              ex.printStackTrace();

}finally{

Log.d("Permissions description", "Null");
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();  
}
permission = permission + requestedPermissions[i] + "    " + pinfo + "\n";    
Log.d("PERMISSIONS" , pm.toString());
}
String lines[] = permission.split("\\n");
return lines;
}
}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
06-25 11:35:00.741: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.741: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40da5f10 android.permission.CAMERA}
06-25 11:35:00.754: W/System.err(776): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 11:35:00.781: W/System.err(776):  at com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.activity.ApkInfo.getPermissions(ApkInfo.java:54)
06-25 11:35:00.781: W/System.err(776):  at com.ibc.android.demo.appslist.activity.ApkInfo.onCreate(ApkInfo.java:34)
06-25 11:35:00.781: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-25 11:35:00.793: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-25 11:35:00.793: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-25 11:35:00.812: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-25 11:35:00.812: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-25 11:35:00.812: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-25 11:35:00.821: W/System.err(776):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 11:35:00.821: W/System.err(776):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 11:35:00.831: W/System.err(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-25 11:35:00.841: W/System.err(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 11:35:00.841: W/System.err(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 11:35:00.851: W/System.err(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-25 11:35:00.851: W/System.err(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-25 11:35:00.851: W/System.err(776):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 11:35:00.861: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.861: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40da7378 android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}
06-25 11:35:00.891: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.891: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40daa998 android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}
06-25 11:35:00.931: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.931: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40dab3b8 android.permission.WAKE_LOCK}
06-25 11:35:00.964: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.964: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40dabf28 android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER}
06-25 11:35:00.991: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:00.991: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40dacaa8 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
06-25 11:35:01.021: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:01.021: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40dad588 android.permission.READ_SMS}
06-25 11:35:01.041: D/Permissions description(776): Null
06-25 11:35:01.041: D/PERMISSION DESCRIPTION(776): PermissionInfo{40dae020 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
```

Why is my ApkInfo activity displaying permission description in such a way? And for some apps it is showing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

The PermissionInfo's loadDescription method returns a charSequence. In my code i'm trying to convert the description information returned from the statement pinfo.loadDescription(pm) to string using the toString method which fails to give me the exact string. Using stringBuilder solves the problem.

```
CharSequence c = pinfo.loadDescription(pm);
StringsBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(c.length());
sb.append(c);
sb.toString();
```

This is a partial answer. I haven't answered the null pointer exception. Still trying to find out the reason behind it.